# Parsing JSON into oracle sql

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I have a table which has CLOB data type. Value of the column is actually JSON data.

```
{"ClassId":32000,"Attributes":
    [
        {"Name":"ID","Value":"4548"},
        {"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},
        {"Name":"HPRECISION","Value":"5"},
        {"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"},
        {"Name":"GEO-METHOD","Value":"96"},
        {"Name":"GEO-PRECISION","Value":"5"},
        {"Name":"GEO-VISIBILITY","Value":"0"}
    ]
}
{"ClassId":30074,"Attributes":
        [
            {"Name":"ID","Value":"265794"},
            {"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},
            {"Name":"HPRECISION","Value":"5"},
            {"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"100"},
            {"Name":"GEO-METHOD","Value":"90"},
            {"Name":"GEO-PRECISION","Value":"5"},
            {"Name":"GEO-VISIBILITY","Value":"0"}
        ]
    }
```

If I select the table table it will show like this

[image]

I need to parse the data so that I can get the output of HMETHODE and HPRECISION.

```
Classid ID      HREF HPRECISION HMETHOD 
30074   265794  -1    5          96     
32000   4548    -1    5          100
```

or may be the output will be like below

[image]

I was trying several method but getting either error or no data found. If anyone can fix this sql it would be very helpful.

```
select ClassId, NAME, VALUE 
from importitem D, 
JSON_TABLE
(
  D.JSON_DATA, '$' COLUMNS
  (
    ClassId NUMBER path '$.ClassId',
    NESTED path '$.Attributes[*]' COLUMNS
    (
    NAME NUMBER PATH '$.Namne',
    Value NUMBER PATH '$.Value'
    )
  )
) J ;
```

Or may be like this, i have tried two different way.

```
SELECT *
FROM   JSON_TABLE(
         '{"ClassId":30074,
           "Attributes":
            [
              {"Name":"ID","Value":"356605"},
              {"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},
              {"Name":"HPRECISION","Value":"5"},
              {"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"},
              {"Name":"GEO-METHOD","Value":"96"},
              {"Name":"GEO-PRECISION","Value":"5"},
              {"Name":"GEO-VISIBILITY","Value":"0"}
            ]
        }',
         '$.Attributes'
         COLUMNS
           ID NUMBER PATH '$.Namne.Value',
           HREF NUMBER PATH '$.Namne.Value',
           HPRECISION NUMBER PATH  '$.Namne.Value',
           HMETHOD NUMBER PATH '$.Namne.Value'
);
```

Comment: version of Oracle Database - is it actually 11 as you have it tagged? Because this is MUCH easier in 12.2 and going forward.

Comment: 1) `jason_table` should be `json_table`. 2) column specifications should be comma separated: `hprecision number, hmethod ...`. Also please, [**do not post images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557), they are unusable

Comment: sorry about that. i changed the screenshot with the code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, you JSON data must be in that this format:

```
{"ClassId":32000,"Attributes":
    [
        {"ID":4548},
        {"HREF":-1},
        {"HPRECISION":5},
        {"HMETHOD":96},
        {"GEO-METHOD":96},
        {"GEO-PRECISION":5},
        {"GEO-VISIBILITY":0}
    ]
}
```

This is the correct format because in this format JSON has a KEYS (ID, HREF, HPRECISION...) and this KEYS has an integer values as (4548, -1, 5). In this case, then our query will be as:

```
SELECT CLASSID, ATRB_ID, HREF, HPRECISION, HMETHOD, GEOMETHOD, GEOPRECISION, GEOVISIBILITY
FROM TABLE2 T1
    CROSS JOIN 
    JSON_TABLE(T1.JSON_DATA, '$' COLUMNS 
        (
            CLASSID INTEGER PATH '$.ClassId', 
            ATRB_ID INTEGER PATH '$.Attributes.ID', 
            HREF INTEGER PATH '$.Attributes.HREF', 
            HPRECISION INTEGER PATH '$.Attributes.HPRECISION', 
            HMETHOD INTEGER PATH '$.Attributes.HMETHOD', 
            GEOMETHOD INTEGER PATH '$.Attributes."GEO-METHOD"', 
            GEOPRECISION INTEGER PATH '$.Attributes."GEO-PRECISION"', 
            GEOVISIBILITY INTEGER PATH '$.Attributes."GEO-VISIBILITY"' 
        )
    )
```

But, if you JSON only in this format:

```
{"ClassId":32000,"Attributes":
    [
        {"Name":"ID","Value":"4548"},
        {"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},
        {"Name":"HPRECISION","Value":"5"},
        {"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"},
        {"Name":"GEO-METHOD","Value":"96"},
        {"Name":"GEO-PRECISION","Value":"5"},
        {"Name":"GEO-VISIBILITY","Value":"0"}
    ]
}
```

So, we can write our query:

```
SELECT CLASSID, ATRB_ID, HREF, HPRECISION, HMETHOD, GEOMETHOD, GEOPRECISION, GEOVISIBILITY
FROM TABLE1 T1
    CROSS JOIN 
    JSON_TABLE(T1.JSON_DATA, '$[*]' COLUMNS 
        (
            CLASSID INTEGER PATH '$.ClassId', 
            ATRB_ID VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[0]."Value"', 
            HREF VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[1]."Value"', 
            HPRECISION VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[2]."Value"', 
            HMETHOD VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[3]."Value"', 
            GEOMETHOD VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[4]."Value"', 
            GEOPRECISION VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[5]."Value"', 
            GEOVISIBILITY VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[6]."Value"' 
        )
    )
```

Results will be:

| CLASSID | ATRB_ID | HREF | HPRECISION | HMETHOD | GEOMETHOD | GEOPRECISION | GEOVISIBILITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32000 | 4548 | -1 | 5 | 96 | 96 | 5 | 0 |
| 30074 | 265794 | -1 | 5 | 100 | 90 | 5 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

execute this query, success executed:

```
SELECT * FROM 
JSON_TABLE('{"ClassId":32000,"Attributes":
    [
        {"Name":"ID","Value":"4548"},
        {"Name":"HREF","Value":"-1"},
        {"Name":"HPRECISION","Value":"5"},
        {"Name":"HMETHOD","Value":"96"},
        {"Name":"GEO-METHOD","Value":"96"},
        {"Name":"GEO-PRECISION","Value":"5"},
        {"Name":"GEO-VISIBILITY","Value":"0"}
    ]
}', '$[*]' COLUMNS 
        (
            CLASSID INTEGER PATH '$.ClassId', 
            ATRB_ID VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[0]."Value"', 
            HREF VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[1]."Value"', 
            HPRECISION VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[2]."Value"', 
            HMETHOD VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[3]."Value"', 
            GEOMETHOD VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[4]."Value"', 
            GEOPRECISION VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[5]."Value"', 
            GEOVISIBILITY VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.Attributes[6]."Value"' 
        )
    )
```